# JtextPane with HTML is too wide

Tags: java, html, jscrollpane, jtextpane

I am trying to create a scrollable JTextPane to display HTML. I have it working with the exception of trying to get the size right. It seems no matter what I do, I cannot effect the width of the pane.

```
JTextPane tp=new JTextPane();
        tp.setSize(300,300);
        tp.setContentType("text/html");
        HTMLDocument html=(HTMLDocument) tp.getDocument();
        html.putProperty("IgnoreCharsetDirective", new Boolean(true));
        HTMLEditorKit htmle=(HTMLEditorKit) tp.getEditorKit();
        try {
            htmle.insertHTML(html,html.getLength(),content,0,0,null);
        } catch (BadLocationException | IOException e) {
            // Should not get here
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        JScrollPane scroll=new JScrollPane(tp,JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED,JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_NEVER);
        scroll.setSize(200,300);
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,scroll,title,JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
```

I've tried setsize on the JTextPane and the JScrollPane but neither effects the width. It seems that it wants set the width to that of the longest < p > tag rather than wrap the HTML within the specified size. What I can't seem to find is a way to set the size of the JOptionPane but my understanding is that should not be necessary if the components are sized correctly. Can someone tell me what I am missing? TIA.

Comment: Could you show where you add your JScrollPane into? It's probably the layout manager the problem

Comment: The JScrollPane is added in the last line. The JOptionPane statement.

Comment: Oh, sorry. Ok, the issue is that JOptionPane calls pack(), and pack() doesn't care about the size. It only considers the preferredSize. Let me write you an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`JOptionPane` calls `pack()`. And `pack()` uses the `preferredSize` of its children to decide of its width and height. By default, the preferred width of a `JTextPane` is the width of the longest line. If you want to change this behaviour,

- Or override the `getPreferredSize` method of the `JTextPane`
- Or use `setPreferredSize` on your `JTextPane` instead of `setSize`

Comment: Bingo! That was it (option 2). Thanks.